# Why can I see my router with iw but not see it with nmcli?

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager, raspbian, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to connect my old raspberry pi 2 magic mirror to the new wifi6 router, but I'm having a world of trouble doing so.  Currently, it can only connect to the old router.  If I scan, I see the old and new router (Typhon & Hermes respectfully).  I've done all the standard stuff with wpa_supplicant.conf to store the SSID and password, but it just will not connect to the new router (other devices do though, with of course the same SSID & password).  I've changed my wpa_supplicant.conf back and forth to have my old router and then replaced those entries with my new router and it only ever works with the old router's info in there.  Below is a console output in which I have given up trying to use wpa_supplicant and tried to use network-manager.  I can see that with `iw dev wlan0 scan` that I see my new router Hermes and the old router Typhon, however when using `nmcli d wifi connect Hermes`, it is no longer seen.  I'm very confused by this and any help or insight would be appreciated.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID
SSID: Typhon
SSID: Echidna
SSID: SpectrumSetup-OD
SSID List
SSID: EmmerFamily
SSID:
* SSID List
SSID: SpectrumSetup-8D
SSID List
SSID: tacocat
OBJECT
SSID: Iris
SSID:
SSID: Kerr_Home
SSID: Hermes
SSID: ATT22M9uIC
pi@raspberrypi:~$ nmcli d wifi connect Hermes password ***
Error: No network with SSID 'Hermes' found.
```

I'm currently using raspbian 10, buster.

Comment: Are there invisible characters in the SSID?

Comment: Nope, but I did get this to work.  It was another issue caused by sneaky processes keeping my wpa_supplicant running and NetworkManager also trying to use wpa_supplicant causing a strange interaction.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by multiple wpa_supplicants running.  Make sure to use `killall wpa_supplicant` and a `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` before doing a `nmcli con up <con-name>`.  If you kill the wpa_supplicant processes, you should see a disconnected status for your wlan0 or wifi device type from `nmcli dev status` which will let you know that restarting the NetworkManager service and then forcing the connection to your router that you have either connected to before or manually created can be forced `up` to establish a connection.  To anyone who finds this and has gone through the struggle, I wish you luck.